# Other ways to add items to an array

Tags: arrays, delphi

Is there a way to fill a Delphi array using something like

```
array = array('this','that','and uh'); // php
array = ['this','that','and uh']; // javascript
```

Or if there's not, maybe you could give me a hint on what I'm trying to do:
I have this array of TButtons. I'm adding some buttons to the array, which should be visible to the user. Using this method of an array, I can easily use a loop to set their visibility property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a dynamic array, and a suitably modern version of Delphi you can use an [array constructor](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types#Dynamic_Arrays).

```
myArray := TArray<string>.Create('this', 'that', 'and uh');
```

If you want to create an array of buttons then it is written so:

```
buttons := TArray<TButton>.Create(btn1, btn2, btn3);
```

And then to iterate over the array of buttons:

```
for button in buttons do
  DoSomething(button);
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what version it was introduced in, but in recent versions of Delphi you've been able to use an alternative syntax like this:

```
type
  TStringArray = array of string;

procedure Test;
var stringArray: TStringArray;
begin
  stringArray := TStringArray.Create('this','that','and uh');
end;
```

Comment: It was introduced after Delphi 7.  I don't have Delphi 2005 or 2006 installed to test against, but this works as expected in Delphi 2007.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a dynamic array like this:

```
type
  TMyButtonArray = array of TButton;

procedure TForm2.Foo;
var
  MyButtonArray: TMyButtonArray;
  I: Integer;
begin
  MyButtonArray := TMyButtonArray.Create(Button1, Button2 {...});
  for I := 0 to High(MyButtonArray) do
    ShowMessage(MyButtonArray[I].Caption);
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use an array, I would use a `TList` instead.  It still gives you array-like syntax for accessing elements of the list via its `[]` operator, but the list itself is dynamically managed by the RTL for you as items are added/removed.

Answer (score 1):

Although you need a modern Delphi version to assign an entire dynamic array *in a single statement*, you can really use *any* Delphi version to construct dynamic arrays holding whatever you want.

```
SetLength(buttons, 3);
buttons[0] := btn1;
buttons[1] := btn2;
buttons[2] := btn3;
```